# Printing out a list from a For-Loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I the following code:

```
z= list(country)
del z[99]

for i in z:
    br=[]
    br=(data[i]['born'])
    print(br)
```

The output I get from this is:
`4.5`
`3.2`
`9.0`
`4.3`

But I want the For loop to give me a list that looks something like:
`[4.5, 3.2 , 9.0 , 4.3]`

In the for loop I tried doing `br=list(data[i]['born'])`, but this gave an error that said `'numpy.float32' object is not iterable` How can I fix this issue?

Comment: maybe `print([data[i]['born'] for i in z])`?

Comment: Are you wanting it to print out the list everytime something is added to it or do you want to create a list and after everything is added print out the final result?

Comment: @Mythalorian I want the list after everything is added (the final result). Like the above comment works but it gives me a list every time something is added, which is not what I am after. I just want One final list.

Comment: @Zegary if you just want a list where you get `born` from `data` then @joanis comment is want you want. Its called a list comprehension and is the standard python way of creating lists like this.

Answer (score 0):

Meaby you can try to use the append method to add each element of the first list into the new empty list that is br=[],
Try this in the for loop:
´´´
br.append(i)
´´´

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways:

```
br = []
for i in z:
    br.append(data[i]['born'])
print(br)
```

or (more concise):

```
print(list(data[i]['born'] for i in x))
```